# Conditional Probability of one RV having maximum among three

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let $X,Y,Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be independent.  What is $\mathbb{P}(X>Y | Y>Z)$?
I've come up with the following solution (is it correct?) but I cannot seem to understand it intuitively.  Specifically, why is it not $2/3$?

Solution:  $\mathbb{P}(X>Y | Y>Z) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>Y \cap Y>Z)}{\mathbb{P}(Y>Z)}$.  By independence, $\mathbb{P}(Y>Z) = \mathbb{P}(Z<Y) = 1/2$.  For the numerator $\mathbb{P}(X>Y \cap Y>Z)$, let $\Omega$ be the sample space and consider the following partitioning of $\Omega$:

$$
\Omega = \{ \{X>Z>Y\}, \{Z>X>Y\}, \{Z>Y>X\}, \boxed{\{X>Y>Z\}}, \{Y>X>Z\}, \{Y>Z>X\}\}
$$
These six sets partitioning $\Omega$ and are all equally likely, with the event of interest boxed.  Hence $\mathbb{P}(X>Y \cap Y>Z) = 1/6$, and so $\mathbb{P}(X>Y | Y>Z) = 1/3$.

Comment: If $Y\gt Z$ then $Y$ is likely to be "big," so the probability that $X\gt Y$ is for sure less than $1/2$. Nice argument by the way, good use of symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice solution.

You've used the fact that the three variables are independent and identically distributed to assert that *symmetry* means that each way of ordering them has an equal probability of occurring.

There are six permutations of ordering, three of them have $Y>Z$, and just one of *those* has $X>Y$.

Alternatively: Given that $Y$ is greater than $Z$ there are three 'places' for $X$ to go: greater than $Y$ and $Z$, between $Y$ and $Z$, or less than $Y$ and $Z$.

$$\begin{align}
\Omega & = \Bigg\{\begin{array}{l} \{X>Z>Y\}, \{Z>X>Y\}, \{Z>Y>X\},\\[0ex] \{X>Y>Z\}, \{Y>X>Z\}, \{Y>Z>X\}\end{array}\Bigg\}
\\[2ex]
\{Y>Z\} & =\Big\{ \{X>Y>Z\}, \{Y>X>Z\}, \{Y>Z>X\}\Big\} 
\\[2ex]
\therefore \mathsf P(X>Y\mid Y>Z) &= 1/3
\end{align}$$

I'm not sure why your intuition would expect otherwise.   Perhaps it's confusing it with the complementary conditional probability?

$$\begin{align}
 \mathsf P(Y>X\mid Y>Z) &= 2/3
\end{align}$$